# accessing variables from angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the code below,

```
<form role="form" name="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName">Isminiz</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Isminizi yaziniz." ng-model="form.name" required >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail">Email Adresiniz</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="xxx@xxx.xxx" ng-model="form.email" required >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputText">Konu</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="inputText" placeholder="Lütfen bize iletmek istediğiniz öneri, istek veya görüşlerinizi yazınız."
                          ng-model="form.content" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="mail-button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="{{scope.isDisabled}}" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || isUnchanged(user)" data-loading-text="Lütfen bekleyiniz..." data-complete-text="Gönderildi!" data-tekrar-text="Tekrar Deneyin">Gönder</button>
            <div>{{ form.name }}</div>
        </form>
```

I am basically trying to access the form.x elements within the controller, but somehow it's not working. 
Are they not in the scope?
Also how do I reset these elements if I need to, also related because I just can't reach them in the controller.

Comment: Where is your controller declared, any errors in the console?

Comment: my controller is declared within the routers, no problem there.  I just don't know the syntax to access those elements.

Comment: Maybe show us what your controller looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You could access those variables inside your controller like:

```
app.controller('Yourcontroller', function(...){

   $scope.submit = function () {
      var name = $scope.form.name;
      var email = $scope.form.email;
      ...............//Rest of the body
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this below worked fine, at last.

```
$scope.form['name']
```